# SMOTE before categorical encoding vs SMOTE after categorical encoding

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, data-mining

I have a small dataset of 977 rows with a class proportion of 77:23.

For the sake of metrics improvement, I have kept my minority class ('default') as class 1 (and 'not default' as class 0).

My input variables are categorical (high cardinality) in nature. So, the below is what I tried.

**Approach 1**

a) Split train and test

b) Apply SMOTE-NC on train data

c) Later, rare_encode and ordinal_encode train and test data separately (due to high cardinal input variables)

d) Build RF model with gridsearch and stratified cross validation, optimizing recall score.

e) Assess the performance

f) No improvement (when compared to imbalanced class. No use of SMOTE NC)

**Approach 2**

a) Split train and test

b) rare_encode and ordinal_encode train and test data separately (due to high cardinal input variables)

c) SMOTE-NC the train data only

d) Build RF model with gridsearch and stratified cross validation, optimizing recall score.

e) Assess the performance

f) No improvement (when compared to imbalanced class. No use of SMOTE NC)

So, my questions are as follows

a) why there is no improvement of the model especially in test data?

b) Am I doing anything incorrectly with the way am doing SMOTE and encoding of categorical variables?

Comment: As I posted for you a few hours ago, class imbalance isn’t much of a problem, so it will be important to say why you find it problematic in order for us to help you.

Comment: I completely agree with @Dave

Comment: See this thread https://twitter.com/CarlosMougan/status/1475756319999205377

Comment: This question in DSE https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/why-smote-is-not-used-in-prize-winning-kaggle-solutions/108363#108363

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he

Comment: Okay, understand. I would like to increase the performance of my nodel in identifying the minority class. I already exhausted feature engineering to the best of my knowlege. I also tried using class weight parameter..but  as the performance of minority class didn't go up, i was trying SMOTE as a last option. Is there any tips that you have on what more can i try to improve the model performance?

Comment: And we don't wish to change the default 0.5 threshold. Is there any other tricks that we can try?

Comment: Another point is, in train set, my recall for minority class is good. Meaning, it is above 80% but in test set, it is only 40%..huge drop

Comment: Why can’t you change the default threshold (or do away with a threshold at all)?

Comment: what do you mean by do away with threshold at all? Sorry, my english knowledge is limited. Modifying threshold seems like a convenient approach to increase the recall of minority class. Meaning, there is no logic/statistics behind it. It is just me simply changing the threshold from 0.5 to 0.6,0.7,0.8 or 0.9 etc to get what I want. When my model works well on train data with a threshold of 0.5, I was expecting the same to happen on test data (with acceptable drop in performance)

Comment: Here are the usual links I post on this topic. Briefly, by doing away with the threshold altogether, you evaluate the probability predictions.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en