# What was used before data augmentation (e.g. SMOTE) to train ML models on imbalanced data? Please provide citations

Tags: machine-learning, data, class-imbalance, data-augmentation

I am seriously curious on how imbalance data was treated in machine learning and statistical learning before modern time data augmentation solutions such as SMOTE appeared.

Please provide citations not only opinions.

Comment: You may want to check [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/106461/14675) and [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/40048)

Comment: @noe Thanks for the input and time. Much appreciated. I was aware of bias introduced by data augmentation techniques thus the origin of my question above. I will leave the question open because I need to know how the ML community trained *vintage* (before data augmentation) ML models on imbalance data.